# Android ConstraintLayout shifts location of spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make gallery with spinner on the bottom of layout which would change directory of gallery. Unfortunately spinner is always shifted up (or maybe RecyclerView constraint is shifted down?). Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProjectActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerProject"
            android:layout_width="141dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is result:
[image]

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: The issue here is that, when u click on the Spinner, it opens and shows up the data above the spinner. This is happening because, the spinner data is shown above of the recyclerview.

Comment: The problem was that I wanted Spinner to be completely separate from RecyclerView and it was overlaping instead. I suppose it's my bad understanding of 'wrap_content'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of vertical linear layout always try to use vertical chaining provided by ConstraintLayout. 
Here is the updated code of your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerProject"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gallery"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerProject"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Yeah, this works as I intended. I wonder why if I change RecyclerView height to 'wrap_content' it messes up it again. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @user13278676 If you want to set height wrap_content of recyclerview then please must use constraint_vertical_bias. I just put the gun on the shoulder of ConstraintLayout by setting recycler view height 0dp.

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you again, you helped me a lot :)